# How can we import tokens into defaultTokens so that they are applied for Community?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, design-tokens

It is not clear how can we define custom tokens to be used in the community in a different file then `defaultTokens.tokens`.

Looks like that only tokens which values are defined in the `defaultTokens.tokens`, are applied.

If a new file is created with token values, they are not applied to LWC components.

[The documentation says](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_create_bundle.htm)

> Your first tokens bundle should be named defaultTokens. The tokens
> defined within defaultTokens are automatically accessible in your
> Lightning components. Tokens defined in any other bundle won’t be
> accessible in your components unless you import them into the
> defaultTokens bundle.

Still, it is not clear how can I import a token file into default tokens.

Does anyone know how can we import tokens into defaultTokens so that they are applied for Community?

Comment: Have you tried to have tokens1 file which extends force:base, and then 
defaultsTokens extends tokens1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard_communities.htm). You need to extend `forceCommunity:base` is your tokens component if you want to make these tokens available for your Community.